# CKEDITOR load data from database AJAX

Tags: json, ckeditor

Hi guys I need to load data from my database into CKEditor. I searched it allready on google but I could not find recent solutions, and I tried some of them but they did not work. I tried this :  `var data = CKEDITOR.ajax.load( data.data[0].name );`

this is my json

```
{"result":true,"message":"Post data success","data":[{"url":"sales","naam":"Sales\/B2B","id":"80","koppelid":"80","omschrijving":"
Sales\/B2B<\/p>\r\n"}]}
```

and here is my AJAX

```
$(document).on('focusout','#select-afdeling',function(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'admin/afdeling/afdeling',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(' #select-afdeling').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
         if (data.result !== true) {

         }else{
            $("#afdeling-naam").val();
            $("#afdeling-naam").attr("value",data.data[0].naam);
            $("#afdeling-naam").val();


         }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SetData()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData).
Example:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('<p>This is the editor data.</p>');
```